# Django model for seat booking

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to design Django model for booking website.
Anyone can book any seats

My Logic is simple, if a seat booked already, it can't be booked later, user can unbook.

i stuck here:

```
from django.db import models
from enum import Enum

class Seat(Enum):
    AA = 1
    AB = 2
    BA = 3
    BB = 4
    CA = 5
    CB = 6

class Hall(models.Model):
    """
    there 6 seats in a hall
    """
    seat = models.CharField(choices=Seat, max_length=2)

class Booking(models.Model):
```

I hope you got my problem. I can handle in frontend like, all the 6 seats will be presented, if user click on a seart, it will be booked and if they clicked on booked seat, it will be unbooked, this is not a big deal to handle.

My problem is only backend, i am stuck in writing the models

like if a seats booked already, it cant be booked again but it can be unbooked only

Can anyone please help me to write this models?

Comment: What is a `Hall` here?

Comment: there is 5 seats in a hall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a `OneToOneField` from `Booking` to `Hall`. This is a `ForeignKey`, but with a `unique=True` constraint (well there is some extra logic for default `related_name` generation, etc., but that is not very relevant here).

We probably need a `ForeignKey` to the user model as well, to keep track of what user has booked what seat.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Booking(models.Model):
    hall = models.OneToOneField(Hall, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In case you aim to create a second `Booking` to the same `Hall`, then it will raise an error. If you remove a `Booking` object, then that `Hall` can be taken again (by creating a `Booking`).